# Fabric objects disappear while zooming or dragging

Tags: fabricjs

In [this link](https://plnkr.co/edit/kBqOHVvzvvAgZL9hwgqY?p=preview) you can see the demo.

When I zoom in or drag, the objects disappear, and then once the animation stops, they become visible.

If I change the Fabric.js version to 1.7.0. then this issue is fixed.

How can I fix this issue using the latest 2.3.6 version?

Below is the code that you can see in the Plunker demo:

```
    (function() {

        if (!window.OpenSeadragon) {
            console.error('[openseadragon-canvas-overlay] requires OpenSeadragon');
            return;
        }


        /**
         * @param {Object} options
         *      Allows configurable properties to be entirely specified by passing
         *      an options object to the constructor.
         * @param {Number} options.scale
         *      Fabric 'virtual' canvas size, for creating objects
         **/
        OpenSeadragon.Viewer.prototype.fabricjsOverlay = function(options) {
            this._fabricjsOverlayInfo = new Overlay(this);
            this._fabricjsOverlayInfo._scale = options.scale;

            return this._fabricjsOverlayInfo;
        };
        // static counter for multiple overlays differentiation
        var counter = (function () {
            var i = 1;

            return function () {
                return i++;
            }
        })();
        // ----------
        var Overlay = function(viewer) {
            var self = this;

            this._viewer = viewer;

            this._containerWidth = 0;
            this._containerHeight = 0;

            this._canvasdiv = document.createElement( 'div');
            this._canvasdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
            this._canvasdiv.style.left = 0;
            this._canvasdiv.style.top = 0;
            this._canvasdiv.style.width = '100%';
            this._canvasdiv.style.height = '100%';
            this._viewer.canvas.appendChild(this._canvasdiv);

            this._canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

            this._id='osd-overlaycanvas-'+counter();
            this._canvas.setAttribute('id', this._id);
            this._canvasdiv.appendChild(this._canvas);
            this.resize();
            this._fabricCanvas=new fabric.Canvas(this._canvas);
            // disable fabric selection because default click is tracked by OSD
            this._fabricCanvas.selection=false;
            // prevent OSD click elements on fabric objects
            this._fabricCanvas.on('mouse:down', function (options) {
                if (options.target) {

                    options.e.preventDefaultAction = true;
                    options.e.preventDefault();
                    options.e.stopPropagation();
                }
            });





            this._viewer.addHandler('update-viewport', function() {
                self.resize();
                self.resizecanvas();

            });

            this._viewer.addHandler('open', function() {
                self.resize();
                self.resizecanvas();
            });


        };

        // ----------
        Overlay.prototype = {
            // ----------
            canvas: function() {
                return this._canvas;
            },
            fabricCanvas: function() {
                return this._fabricCanvas;
            },
            // ----------
            clear: function() {
                this._fabricCanvas.clearAll();
            },
            // ----------
            resize: function() {
                if (this._containerWidth !== this._viewer.container.clientWidth) {
                    this._containerWidth = this._viewer.container.clientWidth;
                    this._canvasdiv.setAttribute('width', this._containerWidth);
                    this._canvas.setAttribute('width', this._containerWidth);
                }

                if (this._containerHeight !== this._viewer.container.clientHeight) {
                    this._containerHeight = this._viewer.container.clientHeight;
                    this._canvasdiv.setAttribute('height', this._containerHeight);
                    this._canvas.setAttribute('height', this._containerHeight);
                }

            },
           resizecanvas: function() {

               var origin = new OpenSeadragon.Point(0, 0);
               var viewportZoom = this._viewer.viewport.getZoom(true);
               this._fabricCanvas.setWidth(this._containerWidth);
               this._fabricCanvas.setHeight(this._containerHeight);
               var zoom = this._viewer.viewport._containerInnerSize.x * viewportZoom / this._scale;
               this._fabricCanvas.setZoom(zoom);
               var viewportWindowPoint = this._viewer.viewport.viewportToWindowCoordinates(origin);
               var x=Math.round(viewportWindowPoint.x);
               var y=Math.round(viewportWindowPoint.y);
               var canvasOffset=this._canvasdiv.getBoundingClientRect();

               var pageScroll = OpenSeadragon.getPageScroll();

               this._fabricCanvas.absolutePan(new fabric.Point(canvasOffset.left - x + pageScroll.x, canvasOffset.top - y + pageScroll.y));

           }

        };

    })();


    App = {
      // ----------
      init: function() {
        var self = this;
        var tileSource = {
          Image: {
            xmlns: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/deepzoom/2008",
            Url: "http://openseadragon.github.io/example-images/highsmith/highsmith_files/",
            Format: "jpg",
            Overlap: "2",
            TileSize: "256",
            Size: {
              Height: "9221",
              Width:  "7026"
            }
          }
        };
        var tileSourceIIIF = {
          "@context": "http://iiif.io/api/image/2/context.json",
          "@id": "https://libimages1.princeton.edu/loris/pudl0001%2F4609321%2Fs42%2F00000001.jp2",
          "height": 7200,
          "width": 5233,
          "profile": [ "http://iiif.io/api/image/2/level2.json" ],
          "protocol": "http://iiif.io/api/image",
          "tiles": [{
            "scaleFactors": [ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 ],
            "width": 1024
          }]
        };
        this.viewer = OpenSeadragon({
          id: "contentDiv",
          prefixUrl: "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/openseadragon@2.3/build/openseadragon/images/",
          tileSources: [{
            tileSource: tileSource,
            width: 1,
            y: 0,
            x: 0
          },
                        {
                          tileSource: tileSourceIIIF,
                          width: 1,
                          y: 0,
                          x: 1.1
                        }]
        });
        // initialize overlay
        var options = {
          scale: 1000
        }
        var overlay = this.viewer.fabricjsOverlay(options);
        // add fabric rectangle
        var rect = new fabric.Rect({
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
          fill: 'red',
          width: 200,
          height: 200
        });
        overlay.fabricCanvas().add(rect);
        // add fabric circle
        var circle = new fabric.Circle({
          left: 1500,
          top: 0,
          fill: 'green',
          radius: 100,
          selectable: true,
          action: 'gravity'
        });
        overlay.fabricCanvas().add(circle);
        // create circle falling animation
        circle.animate('top', '+=1200', {
          onChange: overlay.fabricCanvas().renderAll.bind(overlay.fabricCanvas()),
          duration: 2000,
          easing: fabric.util.ease.easeOutBounce
        });
        circle.animate('scaleY', '-=.1', {
          onChange: overlay.fabricCanvas().renderAll.bind(overlay.fabricCanvas()),
          duration: 1000,
        });
        // animate circle on mouse release (try to drag circle up)
        overlay.fabricCanvas().on('mouse:up', function (options) {
          if (options.target&&(options.target.action=='gravity')) {
            delta=overlay.fabricCanvas().height-options.target.top;
            if (delta>0) {
              circle.animate('top', '+='+(delta+420), {
                onChange: overlay.fabricCanvas().renderAll.bind(overlay.fabricCanvas()),
                duration: 2000,
                easing: fabric.util.ease.easeOutBounce
              });
              circle.animate('scaleY', '-=.1', {
                onChange: overlay.fabricCanvas().renderAll.bind(overlay.fabricCanvas()),
                duration: 1000,
              });
            }
          }
        })
        // add fabric circle with text
        var circle2 = new fabric.Circle({
          left: 930,
          top: 100,
          fill: 'lightgray',
          radius: 120,
          selectable: false,
          action: 'button'
        });
        overlay.fabricCanvas().add(circle2);
        var text = new fabric.Text('Start\n drawing', {
          left: 950,
          top: 150,
          fontSize: 50,
          fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
          textAlign: 'center',
          fill: 'black',
          selectable: false,
          action: 'button'
        });
        overlay.fabricCanvas().add(text);
        overlay.fabricCanvas().freeDrawingBrush.color='red';
        overlay.fabricCanvas().freeDrawingBrush.width=30;
        // start freedrawing mode
        overlay.fabricCanvas().on('mouse:down', function (options) {
          if (options.target&&(options.target.action=='button')) {
            self.viewer.setMouseNavEnabled(false);
            self.viewer.outerTracker.setTracking(false);
            circle2.set('fill','lightgreen');
            overlay.fabricCanvas().isDrawingMode=true;
          }
        });
        $(window).resize(function() {
          overlay.resize();
          overlay.resizecanvas();
        });
      }
    };
    // ----------
    $(document).ready(function() {
      App.init();
    });
```

Comment: I don't have nothing disappearing in your demo

Comment: @JSmith Look at the fabric shapes when you drag the image or zoom in/ out. You will notice that they disappear during that action. I have Version Chrome 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I'm on firefox quantum 61.0.2 and I on't hav this problem I only get the problem of element isappearing when it starts and loads the element sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is due to below code in *resizeCanvas* function.

```
resizeCanvas: function(){    
    //this._fabricCanvas.setWidth(this._containerWidth);
    //this._fabricCanvas.setHeight(this._containerHeight);
}
```

Just comment or remove these two lines, as set canvas size is being called twice (*resize* function was called before *resizeCanvas*).

Here is a working plunker with Fabric 2.3.6: https://plnkr.co/edit/q7KrucdLS7UTbnL1caXR?p=preview

Comment: Great! It might be good to file this as an issue on the plugin as well: https://github.com/altert/OpenseadragonFabricjsOverlay

Comment: It does solve the disappearing issue, however, there is a delay now between openseadragon and fabricjs on image drag event. On fabric.js 1.7.1 we did not have that issue - now on 2.3.6 the image moves first and then the circle catches up with the movement, see this video: https://youtu.be/URsxSb9PBpA. My video recorder did not capture all the frames, but the issue is still visible.

Comment: I just tested on mobile device, and it is much worse that on desktop.